# C++ inheritance and member access issues

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I am learning about OOP with c++ and have run into a situation I don't quite understand.

{Understanding the poor practice of public data members and assuming pointers are not NULL}:

```
...

class Foo {
    public: int a = 0;
}

class Bar: public Foo {
   public: int a = 1;
}

void display (Foo * in) {
    if(in->a)
        cout << "I'M A BAR" << endl;
    else
        cout << "I'M A FOO" << endl;
}

int main() {
    Foo * BAR = new Bar;
    display(BAR); //Displays "I'M A FOO"
    return 0;
}
```

And after a little more tinkering I found that if I instead use constructors to set non const int a values to 0 and 1 respectively AND also output the value form the constructor I see that the value is in fact being set to 1 in BAR, but being evaluated as 0 inside the display function.

I am sorry if this does not make sense, I doubt I really understand well enough to ask the right question, but I am wondering why BAR is not treated like a Bar inside display and how to get it to do so (if possible while still using the base class pointer as an argument).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code makes sense, but it is probably not what you think.

Your class `Bar` has *two* members called `a`, one is `Bar::a`, and one is `Bar::Foo::a`, the member of the `Foo` base class.

When you access either a `Foo` or a `Bar` object through a pointer, like `p->a`, then you *always* get the `a` member of the `Foo` base subobject.

In other words, you cannot "override" data members.

The other code you allude to only has *one* data member, and it would look like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    Foo() : a(0) { }
protected:
    explicit Foo(int n) : a(n) { }
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
    Bar() : Foo(1) { }
};
```

Note how *both* `Foo` and `Bar` only have one single data member `a` in this setup.

Comment: @user1404053: Cool. But don't do this in real code, and use virtual functions instead. :-)